# Is there any javascript library for making a reminder website with alarm sound

Tags: frontend, backend

I am trying to build a web-app for reminding me for doing a certain task with sound alarm.

Answer (score 1):

You could use html5 audio tag and jquery:

```
// appending HTML5 Audio Tag in HTML Body
$('<audio id="chatAudio">
    <source src="notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>').appendTo('body');

// play sound
$('#chatAudio')[0].play();
```

[link](https://www.9lessons.info/2013/04/play-notification-sound-using-jquery.html)

or a simple `<audio>` tag

You could also use the moment library for date-time functions.
https://momentjs.com/ to call the above function.